# Fastest method for finding the closest number in a sorted list many times

Tags: python-3.x, performance

I have a section of code that is sequence searching a list, and I have to constantly look through a large sorted list and find the closest matching value and I do this several thousand times. Is there a more efficient way to perform this search, small time savings would be huge for this area. Is there anyway to take advantage of the fact that I will have to repeat this search constantly that I’m unaware of?

The section that searches the list would be like below:

```
import bisect

x = 2.6
myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]



index = bisect.bisect_left(myList,x)

if len(myList) > index and abs(x-myList[index]) < abs(x-myList[index-1]):
    closestValue = myList[index]
else:
    ClosestValue = myList[index-1]
```

Comment: "*and basically do the search again*" This isn't clear to me.

Comment: There's [`numpy.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) in case the numbers to be searched for are not computed from each other (that part is not clear to me either).

Comment: Some quick research is saying that searchsorted is supposedly faster than bisect_left, I’ll look further into that.